# Why return a symbol of a method instead of just calling the method? (Ruby the Hard Way Ex43)

Tags: ruby

As i study [this](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex43.html) lesson, I see the following blocks and methods.

```
while true
  puts "\n--------"
  room = method(next_room)
  next_room = room.call() #calls central_corridor
end

def death()
  puts "you die"
  Process.exit(1)
end

def central_corridor()
  puts "He's about to pull a weapon to blast you."
  prompt(); action = gets.chomp()

  if action == "shoot!"
    puts "Your laser misses him entirely."
    return :death
```

So returning `:death` clearly launches the `death()` method, but why is this better than simply calling `death()` outright ?

Could not this game go through its entire range of "rooms" just by "calling" other room methods?

Is the purpose simply to teach us about the `method` method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is designed so that each "room" has a method, and the protocol when calling a room method is to do whatever is appropriate for that room, then return the symbol of the next room.  This way the instance of `Game` can keep track of which room is current, which room is next, and call the appropriate method.  It's a reasonable design decision that may seem like overkill at this small scale, but it would make sense if the game were to grow.

Comment: so in a larger game, there's no way for the Game to detect that I'm "in" a particular method (meaning I'm in a particular room), and doing things as the exercise describes is the easiest way to get that info into a variable?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's *no* way, but returning a symbol that can then be stored and/or used to call the method is clear and idiomatic.